# Jest expect statement doesn't wait a promise to be resolved

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a test in jest but I need to work with two contexts however I cannot make the expect statement wait for the promise to be resolved before it fires.

The test:

```
 it("Example test", async() => {
let childComponent = null;
const wrapper = mount (
   <ExampleProviderOne>
      <ExampleConsumerOne>
         {contextOne => {
           context.functionExample = jest.fn();
           context.functionExample.mockImplementationOnce(()=> Promise.resolve(true));
           return(
             <ExampleProviderTwo>
                 <ExampleConsumerTwo>
                    {contextTwo => {return <Component />}}
                 </ExampleConsumerTwo>
             </ExampleProviderTwo>
            )}
      </ExampleConsumerOne>
    </ExampleProviderOne>
});

wrapper.update();
await new Promise(resolve => {
  jest.runAllTimers();
  process.nextTick(resolve);
});

childComponent = wrapper.find(".child-component")
expect(childComponent.length).toBe(1); // exists only after promise is resolved

console.log("End");
```

The End statement is printed and the expect is executed before the promise is resolved which is not what I want because the child component will exist only when the promise is resolved.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's not clear what these components and `.child-component` are. Without being able to run it, it makes it much harder to answer the question.

Comment: I will remove the await thanks, but the problem still stays.

Comment: nextTick may be not enough, use setTimeout. React Testing Library's waitFor is preferable for this kind of tests.